# Get campaign name from LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get in touch with LinkedIn support for the past month now, unfortunately I had no luck getting to the dev team through the account management.

We are using a reporting tool to pull LinkedIn campaign data via their API. We would like to pull Campaign Names which doesn't seem to be possible at the moment referencing https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ref/v2/ads/adcampaigns#get

However, is there any kind of way to retrieve the Campaign Names (ID is making it really hard for us to identify campaigns on the fly)? It seems like such a basic request, I find it hard to believe LinkedIn has no way of doing this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It's Too Late
But I want to clarify others with this problem.
Refer this **official documentation** for crystal clarity [Official linkedin Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaigns#search-for-campaigns)

```
let url = `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAccounts/${adAccountsId}/adCampaigns?q=search&search=(status:(values:List(ACTIVE,DRAFT))`;

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Linkedin-Version", "202310");
headers.append("X-Restli-Protocol-Version", "2.0.0");

fetch(url, {
method: 'GET',
headers: headers,
credentials: 'include'  // Add this line if you need to include credentials
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
console.log(data);
})
.catch(error => {
console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Please Make sure to send the access token with the authorization headers.

Answer (score 0):

A little further down that page you referenced is a section called "FINDER" with this:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2?q=statuses&statuses=ACTIVE

Options are ACTIVE, PAUSED, ARCHIVED, COMPLETED, OR CANCELLED

You will get the "name":"MY_CAMPAIGN_NAME" field there. That's the only place I've found it so far.